# pretty urls in address bar with a ServiceStack.Net REST server and a jQuery client

Tags: jquery, rest, url-routing, servicestack

I want pretty urls in the browser address bar like: http://domain.com/userName

Is this possible when the jQuery client is completely separated from the ServiceStack server?
Without any MVC or templating on the server side.

For example:

user types in the address bar:   http://domain.com/userName
and gets his profile gui and not the JSON.

How can this be achieved with the greatest separation between client and server ?
In other words: What is the best client side JavaScript solution for pretty urls ?

Comment: javascript/jQuery has no control over what server outputs for a given url

Comment: can routes be used as an alternative for a fairly complex app?(http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like routes with a one page app are the only way to achieve pretty urls on client side:
http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/